# recording game object movement values for use in interpolation

Tags: gameobject

I am looking for a way to record the position and velocity of each object in a game scene relative to the viewing camera and cross-reference that with direct extraction of the game's models, textures, and post-processing effects in order to automatically draw a new frame based on directly interpolating the object positions.

This is for a few games, all of which already exist and were made by other people

the list of games is as follows:

PC Building Simulator,
Scrap Mechanic,
BeamNG.drive,
Minecraft (modded)